# Was Rin's death the only reason which has led Obito to start Fourth Great War?

Tags: naruto

It seems like there weren't any other reasons for Obito to consider Mugen Tsukuyomi.

Did Obito had other motivation, except Rin's death?

Comment: madara uchiha perhaps who fueled his rage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rin's death was just the final spark to make Obito start the Fourth Great War. His hatred towards "evil" shinobis, current world and the desire to fix the world were evident from a long while (him always trying to compete with Kakashi to get stronger and save his allies). He was searching for a way to bring "peace" to everyone which is when Madara came in, in the times of despair Madara presented him a hope of "Infinite Tsukuyomi" which to the strong desires of Obito looked like the perfect solution. I won't just call it manipulation, for that time, the goals of Madara and Obito were quite similar and it was more of an agreement than just manipulation. Madara found the perfect candidate to carry his will, Obito found the perfect solution he deemed "correct" in his twisted, despaired mind.

Answer (score 3):

Manipulation by Madara Uchiha. Obito was played by a master manipulator, and sent down the rage and impossible fixes path because Madara found him and pushed him that way.

In my opinion.

Comment: Can you provide any sourcing for this?

Comment: unfortunately it really seems so. Such huge lack of motivation for such powerfull character

Comment: Some call it brainwashing.

Answer (score 0):

It actually keeps both powers. In Sasuke’s fight with Danzō in volume 51, he used a weaker version of Itachi’s genjutsu. On the Gokage Summit Attack, he is able to use his own power of controlling Amaterasu flames. So they can use both their original and the previous owner’s Mangekyou Powers.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely. Rin dying was the first catalyst for Obito going down Madara's path. The events after cemented Obito going that way. He mentions after he's beaten in the war that he tried to find light in the world while he was travelling as Madara but every time he was let down. What would have kept Obito thinking the world was shit due to the system of the shinobi? Itachi's entire life, Nagato's past, Kisame's whole stick comes to mind big time.
As Obito said what brought him to complete dispair was the entire state of the world.